# Can't manage to give two arguments from a fil to bash script : command not found

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I'm new to bash script, it is interesting, but somehow I'm struggling with everything.

I have a file, separated by tab "\t" with 2 infos : a string and a number.
I'd like to use both info on each line into a bash script in order to look into a file for those infos.
I'm not even there, I'm struggling to give the arguments from the two columns as two arguments for bash.

```
#/!bin/bash
FILE="${1}"
while read -r line
do
READ_ID_WH= "echo ${line} | cut -f 1"
POS_HOTSPOT= echo '${line} | cut  -f 2'
echo "read id is : ${READ_ID_WH} with position ${POS_HOTSPOT}"
done < ${FILE}
```

and my file is :

```
ABCD\t1120
ABC\t1121
```

I'm launching my command with

```
./script.sh file_of_data.tsv
```

What I finally get is :

```
script.sh: line 8: echo ABCD 1120 | cut -f 1: command not found
```

I tried a lot of possibilities by browsing SO, and I can't make it to divide my line into two arguments to be used separately in my script :(

Hope you can help me :)

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes cause the shell to look for a command whose name is the string between the quotes.

Apparently you are looking for

```sh
while IFS=$'\t' read -r id hotspot; do
    echo "read id is: $id with position $hotspot"
done <"$1"
```

You generally want to avoid capturing things into variables you only use once, but the syntax for that is

```
id=$(echo "$line" | cut -f1)
```

See also [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable). You can never have whitespace on either side of the `=` assignment operator (or rather, incorrect whitespace changes the semantics to something you probably don't want).

Comment: Thank you so much, you save my evening.
I have a lot of issues getting the "philosophy" about bash scripting for reasons, would you recommend a tutorial/course in particular? (I don't have an informatic background)
best

Comment: The [Stack Overflow `bash` tag info page](/tags/bash/info) has a brief reading list.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space after the equals sign on lines 5 and 6, so it thinks you are looking for an executable file named `echo ABCD 1120 | cut -f 1` and asking to execute it while assigning the variable READ_ID_WH to the empty string, rather than assigning the string you want to the variable.